# Insert dynamic data based on array size in json mule 4

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

**Existing JSON:**

```
{
 "name":"abc",
"place": "äbc"
}
```

**I have a separte array as below:**

```
    [documentDetails:{
    "name" : "doc1",
    "size" : "5"
    },
    documentDetails:{
    "name" : "doc1",
    "size" : "5"
    }
    ]
```

**Final JSON REQUIRED:**

```
 {
     "name":"abc",
    "place": "äbc",
documentDetails:{
    "name" : "doc1".
    "size" : "5"
    },
    documentDetails:{
    "name" : "doc1".
    "size" : "5"
    }
    }
```

How can I achieve the final json ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var in1 = {
 "name":"abc",
"place": "äbc"
}

var in2 = [
    documentDetails:{
    "name" : "doc1",
    "size" : "5"
    },
    documentDetails:{
    "name" : "doc1",
    "size" : "5"
    }
]
---
{
    (in1),
    (in2)
}
```

Note that your "separate array" has typos.  Fixed to the best of my understanding.

Comment: I didn't use the round brackets . Thanks for the help